# Crear una barra de acción

Tags: android-studio

Veran, estoy intentando crear una barra de acción, para lo cual lo primero es crear un fichero en res/values llamado mimenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <menu xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >

        <item
            android:id= "@+id/refresh"
            android:icon=" @drawable/ic_refrescar"
            android:showAsAction= "always"
            android:title= "refrescar" />
        <item
            android:id= "@+id/picture"
            android:icon= "@drawable/ic_foto"
            android:showAsAction= "ifroom|withText"
            android:title= "foto" />
        <item
            android:id= "@+id/search"
            android:icon= "@drawable/ic_buscar"
            android:showAsAction= "never"
            android:title= "buscar" />

    </menu>
</resources>
```

Una vez que lo he hecho, en java creo una función llamada "onCreateOptionsMenu":

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.**menu**.mimenu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Sin embargo, me sale un error (la parte que he puesto en negrita) debido a que la ruta indicada es erronea. ¿Que se me habra pasado?
Por cierto, estoy usando la API 18.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado. De entrada, resulta que no devia poner el fichero en res/values, sino en res/menu.
Lo siguiente es que la variable android:icon es opcional, es para que el botón se muestre como una imagen. Si no se pone lo que se mostrara es lo indicado en android:title.

Por ultimo, para sacar provecho de la barra de acción, necesito el uso de un metodo de tipo boolean llamado onOptionsItemSelected. Paso un ejemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   switch(item.getItemId()){
       case R.id.action_nuevo: 
           Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "Crear nuevo aviso");
           return true;
       case R.id.action_salir: 
           finish();
           return true;
       default:
        return false;
   }
}
```